# How to detect the location of a grid of letters in an image with openCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm writing a program that takes an image that has a grid of 4 by 4 letters somewhere in that image.

E.g.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PihQH.png)

I want to read these letters into my program and for that I'm using pytesseract for the OCR.

Before feeding the image to pytesseract I do some preprocessing with openCV to increase the odds of pytesseract working correctly.

This is the code I use for this:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('my_image.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_pre_processed = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

And these are some sample outputs of img_pre_processed:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Phv.jpg) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROhge.jpg) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuDXL.jpg)

Since the letters in the grid are spaced apart pytesseract has a difficult time to read them when I give the entire image as input. So it would be helpful if I knew the coordinates of every letter, then I could edit the image in such a way that pytesseract can always recognise them.

I started to try and solve this problem on my own and the solution I'm coming up with might work but it's getting rather complicated. So I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

At the moment I'm using the cv2.findContours() function to get all the contours of the objects in the image. For every contour I calculate the center coordinates and the area of the box you would be able to draw around it. I then sort these by area to get the largest contours. Now here it starts to get more and more complicated. I can't just say take the biggest 16 contours, because there might be unwanted objects in the picture that have a bigger area than the 16 letters that I want. Also some letters like O, P, Q,... have 2 contours and their inner contour might even be bigger than another letters outer contour like the letter I for example.

E.g. This is an image with the 18 biggest contours marked with a green box. [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QueGn.jpg)

So to continue with my way of attacking the problem I would have to write an algorithm that finds the contours that are most likely part of the grid while ignoring the contours that are unwanted and also the inner contours of letters that have 2 contours.

While this is possible, I'm wondering if there is be a better way of doing this.

Somebody told me that if you can filter the image in such a way that everything gets more blurry so that all the letters become blobs. That it might be possible to do a pattern detection with 4x4 grid of blobs. But I don't know how to do that or if that's possible.

So if somebody knows a better way to tackle this problem or if you know how to execute the plan of attack I mentioned earlier that would be most helpfull.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just get the large white box and then cut out the 16 letters by fixed position as the grid seems to be the same in each of your images?

Comment: Well it might not always have that white square. It could be that everything in the background is white.
But do you know how to get the coordinates of the white square? Because if you know how to do that, that could be usefull.

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-detect-the-location-of-a-grid-of-letters-in-an-image-with-opencv-and-python/9819

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter the bounding rectangles by width and height. As this is a rule based approach, it may need more example images to fine tune the filter rules.

```
import cv2


# get bounding rectangles of contours
img = cv2.imread('img.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
bbox = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in contours]

# filter rectangles by width and height
for x, y, w, h in bbox:
    if (4 < w < 200) and (30 < h < 200):
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I wasn't aware of the cv2.boundingRect() function.
I had written a function myself to calculate these boxes, so this is most helpfull.
One thing I'm thinking about is that those values to filter the rectangles are pretty dependent on the size of the grid in the image and also the resolution of the image.
Is there a way to generalise this, so it will always work no matter how big the grid or the image is?

Comment: @pilu This is a rule based approach. You didn't define many constraints, so I started with the most obvious rule I could see as an example. If you want ro improve this you'll need more information for the rules, depending on the images that you expect and features that they include. Which features are fixed and which are variable? Can you add more such constraints or typical images to your question?

Comment: One first rule could be: "Only consider bounding boxes that are at least apart to other boxes at a distance of 80% of their own height or width." (Let the distance of bounding boxes be defined by the minimal distance of their shapes.) Does this apply?