# How to extract the white rings in the given image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image of a robot moving, I need to extract the white rings

[image: white rings]

in order to find the midpoint of the robot. But thresholding is not giving correct result:

[image: result]

What method should I try to extract only the white rings.

```
%code to get second image
img=imread('data\Image13.jpg');
hsv=rgb2hsv(img);
bin=hsv(:,:,3)>0.8;
```

Comment: Better use roi.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please look for `cv2.findContours`, `cv2.contourArea` or `cv2.cv2.boundingRect`. There are tons of examples. If you have further issues please edit your question and tell exactly where you got stuck!

Comment: @toyotaSupra I need the roi, I cannot manually feed in the roi.

Comment: @Markus Can you elaborate on how i can use these methods to get only the white rings. I have been stuck at this step, as none of the thresholding or contour methods i tried did not work

Comment: Which programming language do you use? You have tagged `opencv` but you have also tagged `matlab`. Are you looking for an answer in python? Can you add the tag? Can you share your code? Many open questions. I guess this is why people downvote your post.

Comment: @ssuraj. How did you get second image?

Comment: @Markus I am ok with a solution that works either in matlab or open-cv(python or c++). Hence i tagged both.  I have edited to include the code

Comment: @toyotaSupra included the code to get second image

Comment: You can start with the code from this answer and adjust it to your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73330898/18667225 If you have any issues, please let us know.

Comment: @Markus I am unsure of what element of that answer/question i use as it is simpply a matter of finding bounding rectangles. But i have an idea to use the area and segregate and ignore contour with areas above a given value. I am planning to try this (though noise is not constant, so it might not work)

Comment: How many rings one or eleven rings?

Comment: @toyotaSupra all the eleven rings

Comment: @Markus The stack overflow question you mentioned does not seem relevant to my question

Comment: I would recommend removing the white background, literally move that whiteboard or hang a black cloth over it... and using retroreflective tape instead of those plain rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

# get bounding rectangles of contours
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# filter contours by area and width
contours = [c for c in contours if (50 < cv2.contourArea(c) < 500) and cv2.boundingRect(c)[2] > 20]

# draw contours on empty mask
out = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(out, contours, -1, 255, -1)

cv2.imwrite('out.png', out)
```

Output:

[image]